# Cannot get post working in Angular2

Tags: node.js, ionic2, ionic3

[image: Postman header]

[image: Postman body]

So i'm trying to authenticate in my angular application. I attended headers and created an stringified body. I also looked at serveral other forum post about sending post requests in postman but i cannot get it working.

```
getToken()
{
    console.log('started getting of token');

    //get username and password from local storage

    //Send username and password via body

    let headers = new Headers();
    let body = JSON.stringify({
        name: 'test',
        password: 'test'
    });

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    this.jwt =  this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate/', {
        headers: headers,
        body: body
    }).map(res => res.text()).subscribe(data => console.log(data));

}
```

So above is my code. I know it might be a little silly thing but I cannot get it working. 
I get the error that the user cannot be found. That happens when the username is wrong, and when the username does not exsist in the database. So that a little extra tricky as well.

Who knows what the stupid mistake is that I made?

Comment: try `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Comment: Does unfortunately not work, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Debug your api, check what your getting in name and password param.

Comment: I suggest you drop the JSON.stringify and content type application/x-www.... unless you are very sure your backend needs it. In case your backend is built using php then it might not understand application/json by default. Have a look at this https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/json_request_body.html

I also note that your postman returns just one header, that's very unlikely in a REST API scenario where cors and content-type are expected

Comment: In your case I think it might be much easier to debug a GET request than a POST request just in case the issue is in your backend. Check if you can fetch a simple JSON page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your service.ts file.

```
import { Http, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
  getToken()
  {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('name', test);
    body.set('password', test);
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate/", body, headers).map(response => response.json());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to send post request

```
this.jwt =  this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate/',body,headers).map(res => res.text()).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Doing that end me up with an empty body.

Comment: You have only replaced that 'this.jwt=...' line, right?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, I think it's something wrong with the api. So thanks for your help I will just continue debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This code is what I use for post request

```
send_request_post(url: String, data:{})
{
    var headerPost  = new Headers
    ({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json ;charset=utf-8'
    })

    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headerPost})
    .toPromise()
    .then
    (
        response => 
        {
            console.log(response);
        }
    )
}
```